# convergence of function series using Weierstrass M-test

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, sequence-of-function

I am trying to examine uniform convergence of series $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\frac{x^2}{n^4+x^4}}$$
For $x \ \in \mathbb{R}$. What i've tried: $$\text{assume } x \in [-R, R] \text{ for some } R>0$$
$$|\frac{x^2}{n^4+x^4}| = \frac{x^2}{n^4+x^4} \leq\frac{x^2}{n^4}\leq \frac{R^2}{n^4}$$
And since $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\frac{R^2}{n^4}}$ converges, the original series converges uniformly on $[-R, R]$. I am pretty sure that only proves continuity on $\mathbb{R}$. I have not been able to prove it for  $\mathbb{R}$, how should I go about it?

Comment: When you wrote “that only proves continuity on $\Bbb R$”, did you mean to write “that only proves uniform convergence on $[-R,R]$“?

Comment: I meant what I wrote, but now I am not sure if it's correct. My original thought was: since it uniformly converges on every $[-R, R]$, then it must be continuous on $[-R, R]$ too, and this implies it is continous on $\mathbb{R}$. But even if true (I'll think about it), that does not bring me closer to determining if it converges uniformly on $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: Yes, if it converges uniformly on every interval $[-R,R]$, then the sum is a continuous function. But what are are really after? A proof that the series converges uniformly on $\Bbb R$. Or a proof that the sum of the series is a continuous function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want uniform convergence over $\mathbb{R}$, observe that:
$$n^4+x^4 \geq 2n^2 x^2$$
for any $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $x \in \mathbb{R}$. This is just the AM-GM inequality. Hence:
$$\frac{x^2}{n^4+x^4} \leq \frac{1}{2n^2}$$

In particular, for any $x \in \mathbb{R}$:
$$\sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \frac{x^2}{n^4+x^4} \leq \sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \frac{1}{2n^2}$$

And this proves uniform convergence over $\mathbb{R}$.